# Beat input in Logstash is losing fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logstash, filebeat, elastic-beats

I have the following infrastructure:

ELK installed as docker containers, each in its own container. And on a virtual machine running CentOS I installed nginx web server and Filebeat to collect the logs.
I enabled the nginx module in filebeat.

```
> filebeat modules enable nginx
```

Before starting filebeat I set it up with elasticsearch and installed it's dashboards on kibana.

config file (I have removed unnecessary comments from the file):

```
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.kibana:
  host: "172.17.0.1:5601"

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["172.17.0.1:9200"]
```

then to set it up in elasticsearch and kibana

```
> filebeat setup -e --dashboards
```

> This works fine. In fact if I keep it this way everything works perfectly. I can use the collected logs in kibana and use the dashboards for NGinX I installed with the above command.

I want though to pass the logs through to Logstash.
And here's my Logstash configuration uses the following pipelines:

```
- pipeline.id: filebeat
  path.config: "config/filebeat.conf"
```

filebeat.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}


#filter {
#  mutate {
#    add_tag => ["filebeat"]
#  }
#}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch0:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }

  stdout { }
}
```

Making the logs go through Logstash the resulting log is just:

```
{
        "offset" => 6655,
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-02-20T13:34:06.886Z,
       "message" => "10.0.2.2 - - [20/Feb/2019:08:33:58 -0500] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.98 Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36\" \"-\"",
          "beat" => {
         "version" => "6.5.4",
            "name" => "localhost.localdomain",
        "hostname" => "localhost.localdomain"
    },
        "source" => "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
          "host" => {
                   "os" => {
             "version" => "7 (Core)",
            "codename" => "Core",
              "family" => "redhat",
            "platform" => "centos"
        },
                 "name" => "localhost.localdomain",
                   "id" => "18e7cb2506624fb6ae2dc3891d5d7172",
        "containerized" => true,
         "architecture" => "x86_64"
    },
       "fileset" => {
          "name" => "access",
        "module" => "nginx"
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
         "input" => {
        "type" => "log"
    },
    "prospector" => {
        "type" => "log"
    }
}
```

A lot of fields are missing from my object. There should have been many more structured information

> #### UPDATE: This is what I'm expecting instead

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-6.5.4-2019.02.20",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "ssJPC2kBLsya0HU-3uwW",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "offset": 9639,
    "nginx": {
      "access": {
        "referrer": "-",
        "response_code": "404",
        "remote_ip": "10.0.2.2",
        "method": "GET",
        "user_name": "-",
        "http_version": "1.1",
        "body_sent": {
          "bytes": "3650"
        },
        "remote_ip_list": [
          "10.0.2.2"
        ],
        "url": "/access",
        "user_agent": {
          "patch": "3578",
          "original": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.98 Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
          "major": "71",
          "minor": "0",
          "os": "Ubuntu",
          "name": "Chromium",
          "os_name": "Ubuntu",
          "device": "Other"
        }
      }
    },
    "prospector": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "read_timestamp": "2019-02-20T14:29:36.393Z",
    "source": "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
    "fileset": {
      "module": "nginx",
      "name": "access"
    },
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "@timestamp": "2019-02-20T14:29:32.000Z",
    "host": {
      "os": {
        "codename": "Core",
        "family": "redhat",
        "version": "7 (Core)",
        "platform": "centos"
      },
      "containerized": true,
      "name": "localhost.localdomain",
      "id": "18e7cb2506624fb6ae2dc3891d5d7172",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
      "name": "localhost.localdomain",
      "version": "6.5.4"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-02-20T14:29:32.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1550672972000
  ]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are parsing the log message. There's an example in the logstash documentation on this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html#parsing-nginx

Comment: thanks man. that is helpful. although I thought that since filebeat, if sending directly to elasticsearch sends the full object, passing through logstash should do the same. And I had this working in my local pc. Now I can't get it to work. I wasn't doing any filtering in logstash and I had it working. that's why it's so strange to me. @baudsp

Comment: I don't know. I have very little experience with filebeat, I didn't even knew it could do some parsing of its own.

Comment: @baudsp if you have time try using filebeat directly with elasticsearch and kibana. install the dashboards and indexes like this: filebeat setup --dashboards. enable some module, even the system module: filebeat modules enable system and then run it. Try opening one of the system dashboards on kibana. it's pretty nice.

Comment: @baudsp your first comment almost worked. It is parsing the data, not enough so to work with the predefined kibana dashboards but I will build them from there. Post it as an answer and I'll accept that if you want!

Comment: Looks like this same discussion was also held here:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-input-in-logstash-is-losing-fields/169460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logstash configuration, it doesn't look like you are parsing the log message.

There's an [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html#parsing-nginx) in the logstash documentation on how to parse nginx logs:

> **Nginx Logs**
>
> The Logstash pipeline configuration in this example shows how to ship and parse access and error logs collected by the nginx Filebeat module.
>
> ```
>   input {
>     beats {
>       port => 5044
>       host => "0.0.0.0"
>     }
>   }
>   filter {
>     if [fileset][module] == "nginx" {
>       if [fileset][name] == "access" {
>         grok {
>           match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[nginx][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][body_sent][bytes]} \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][referrer]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][agent]}\""] }
>           remove_field => "message"
>         }
>         mutate {
>           add_field => { "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }
>         }
>         date {
>           match => [ "[nginx][access][time]", "dd/MMM/YYYY:H:m:s Z" ]
>           remove_field => "[nginx][access][time]"
>         }
>         useragent {
>           source => "[nginx][access][agent]"
>           target => "[nginx][access][user_agent]"
>           remove_field => "[nginx][access][agent]"
>         }
>         geoip {
>           source => "[nginx][access][remote_ip]"
>           target => "[nginx][access][geoip]"
>         }
>       }
>       else if [fileset][name] == "error" {
>         grok {
>           match => { "message" => ["%{DATA:[nginx][error][time]} \[%{DATA:[nginx][error][level]}\] %{NUMBER:[nginx][error][pid]}#%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][tid]}: (\*%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][connection_id]} )?%{GREEDYDATA:[nginx][error][message]}"] }
>           remove_field => "message"
>         }
>         mutate {
>           rename => { "@timestamp" => "read_timestamp" }
>         }
>         date {
>           match => [ "[nginx][error][time]", "YYYY/MM/dd H:m:s" ]
>           remove_field => "[nginx][error][time]"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

I know it doesn't deal with why filebeat doesn't send to logstash the full object, but it should give a start on how to parse the nginx logs in logstash.

Comment: Is there anything similar to configure auditbeat in logstash? I can't find any examples.

Comment: @500Servererror I haven't found anything in the documentation. You'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: strangely enough auditbeat is sending all the fields

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem as described in the original question: Filebeat sending Nginx logs through Logstash instead of directly to Elastic Search results in pretty much all of the interesting fields being missing (everything I want to see is still only in the message field).  I have the Logstash configuration exactly as above (from the same source), so unless I'm missing something else, this does not appear to be the solution.

Comment: probably depends on the ELK stack version. this was already answered almost 1 year ago.

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by @baudsp was mostly correct, but it was incomplete.  I had exactly the same problem, and I also had exactly the same [filter mentioned in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html#parsing-nginx) (and in @baudsp's answer), but documents in Elastic Search still did not contain any of the expected fields.

I finally found the problem: because I had Filebeat configured to send Nginx logs via the [Nginx module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-nginx.html) and not the [Log input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html), the data coming from Logbeat didn't match quite what the example Logstash filter was expecting.

The conditional in the example is `if [fileset][module] == "nginx"`, which is correct if Filebeat was sending data from a Log input.  However, since the log data is coming from the Nginx module, the `fileset` property doesn't contain a `module` property.

To make the filter work with Logstash data coming from the Nginx module, the conditional needs to be modified to look for something else.  I found the `[event][module]` to work in place of `[fileset][module]`.

The working filter:

```
filter {
  if [event][module] == "nginx" {
    if [fileset][name] == "access" {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[nginx][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][body_sent][bytes]} \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][referrer]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][agent]}\""] }
        remove_field => "message"
      }
      mutate {
        add_field => { "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "[nginx][access][time]", "dd/MMM/YYYY:H:m:s Z" ]
        remove_field => "[nginx][access][time]"
      }
      useragent {
        source => "[nginx][access][agent]"
        target => "[nginx][access][user_agent]"
        remove_field => "[nginx][access][agent]"
      }
      geoip {
        source => "[nginx][access][remote_ip]"
        target => "[nginx][access][geoip]"
      }
    }
    else if [fileset][name] == "error" {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => ["%{DATA:[nginx][error][time]} \[%{DATA:[nginx][error][level]}\] %{NUMBER:[nginx][error][pid]}#%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][tid]}: (\*%{NUMBER:[nginx][error][connection_id]} )?%{GREEDYDATA:[nginx][error][message]}"] }
        remove_field => "message"
      }
      mutate {
        rename => { "@timestamp" => "read_timestamp" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "[nginx][error][time]", "YYYY/MM/dd H:m:s" ]
        remove_field => "[nginx][error][time]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, documents in Elastic Search have all of the expected fields:
[image: Screenshot of Nginx access log entry in Elastic Search]

> **Note:** You'll have the same problem with other [Filebeat modules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.4/filebeat-modules.html), too.  Just use `[event][module]` in place of `[fileset][module]`.